# Get the coordinates of a point as it rotates around the center of a rectangle

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations

I am trying to get the coordinates of a point as it rotates around the center of a rectangle (the point will always be on the perimeter).

So if the rectangle dimensions are 400 x 200 and we declare that due east from center is zero degrees, the starting point (x,y) at zero degrees is (400, 100). Given the center of the rectangle (a,b) is at (200,100), I see [from this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112713/rotate-a-point-around-a-rectangle?newreg=5cc8055768594f5d993cf50fd3fa3d72) that rotating 180 degrees can be solved with the formula (2a-x, 2b-y)

Can you help me with a solution for any degree of rotation?

**UPDATE** In case you were curious, I am programming in javascript trying to calculate the starting and ending points on a canvas rectangle when working with gradients and knowing the gradient degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us place the origin of coordinates in the center of your rectangle.
Let $a=400$, $b=200$ be the side lengths of the rectangle.

For "small" angles $\alpha$, namely, when $|\alpha|<\arctan{b\over a}$, we have
$$
(x,y) = ({a\over2},{a\over2}\tan\alpha).
$$
Can you continue for larger angles? The whole solution may look like this:
$$
(x,y) = ({a\over2},{a\over2}\tan\alpha) 
                       \quad\mbox{ for }|\alpha|<\arctan{b\over a} \ \ 
                        \mbox{ or } \ \ |\alpha-2\pi|<\arctan{b\over a},
                        \quad\mbox{(right)}
$$
$$
(x,y) = (-{b\over2}\tan(\alpha-{\pi\over2}),{b\over2}) 
               \ \quad\qquad\mbox{ for }|\alpha-{\pi\over2}|<\arctan{a\over b},
                        \quad\mbox{(top)}
$$
$$
(x,y) = (-{a\over2},-{a\over2}\tan(\alpha-\pi)) 
                       \qquad\mbox{ for }|\alpha-\pi|<\arctan{b\over a},
                       \qquad\mbox{(left)}
$$
$$
(x,y) = ({b\over2}\tan(\alpha-{3\pi\over2}),-{b\over2}) 
                     \qquad\mbox{ for }|\alpha-{3\pi\over2}|<\arctan{a\over b}
                        \qquad\mbox{(bottom).}
$$
(The formulas can still be simplified a little.)

JavaScript has the function $\,\tt Math.atan2(a,b)$ (arc tangent of a ratio) that is very suitable for checking conditions like the above.

Comment: The angle can be anywhere from 0 - 360 degrees

Comment: By asking, "Can you continue for larger angles?" were you asking if I can extrapolate your answer or were you asking if the the point can travel greater than 90 degrees (presuming by small you mean acute angles). The answer to the first is no, I cannot extrapolate and the answer to the second is, yes as mentioned in the comment above. My trig is really rusty.

Comment: I added formulas for the full circle. Hopefully they work :)

Comment: Thank you. It will take some time to verify!

Comment: Just fixed some errors.

Comment: Finally verified it. Thank you!